# How to make html banner smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have make the banner for my html, where you can click next to see next slide with some text on that slide, I imagine it to transition smoothly but I seems can't make it smooth, whenever I tried some codes from Google it ruin the whole thing.

Below is my HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".img-slider .slide");
const prevButton = document.querySelector(".img-slider .prev")
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".img-slider .next");
let currentSlide = 1;

function changeSlide(n) {
  showSlide((currentSlide += n));
}

function showSlide(n) {
  if (n > slides.length) {
    currentSlide = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    currentSlide = slides.length;
  }
  slides.forEach((imgSlider) => {
    imgSlider.style.display = "none";
  });
  slides[currentSlide - 1].style.display = "block";
}

showSlide(currentSlide);

prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeSlide(-1);
});

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeSlide(+1);
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.slider-container .img-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
  -o-object-position: 0 -120px;
  object-position: 0 -120px;
  display: block;
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide .info h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide .info p {
  color: #fff;
  background: #171716;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.slider-container .img-slider .slide.active {
  transition: 2s;
  transition-property: -webkit-clip-path;
  transition-property: clip-path;
  transition-property: clip-path, -webkit-clip-path;
}

.slider-container .prev,
.slider-container .next {
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.slider-container .next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.slider-container .prev:hover,
.slider-container .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="img-slider">
    <div class="slide active">
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="info">
        <h2>High Quality Manufacturing Processes</h2>
        <p>
          From know-how to designing, production, testing, and the final delivery with utmost priority given to the quality standards.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="constructio.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Superior Sealing Technology</h2>
        <p>
          Our legacy of 30 years has driven us constantly to grow with the challenging needs of superior sealing technology.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="tunnel.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Our Legacy</h2>
        <p>
          At Sealmatic we care. We ensure that we make each of our production processes safe for our employees and our environment.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="reservoir.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Longest Standing Experience</h2>
        <p>
          Our collective knowledge of many years in the sealing industry has helped us create programs that can solve any sealing questions at the click of a button.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="factory2.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Global Sales &amp; Service</h2>
        <p>
          Our aim at Sealmatic is to ensure utmost satisfaction of our customers where we ensure international quality and close proximity.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" id="prev" onclick="changeSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" id="next" onclick="changeSlide(+1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried googling other options but no answer, I'm new to this so I really have no clue how to make the transition smoothly

Can anyone tell me where I can improve?

Comment: Hi NamQi Ch. and welcome to SO. I believe you're trying create a slider / carousel transition which could explain why you're coming up empty on your search. A couple of things that are quick to point out. The `display` property cannot be animated or transitioned. If you're trying to make a fade-in / fade-out effect, then use the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) property and transition that. There seems to be a syntax error in your JS: `\>` and `\<`. Be aware of that. Please add the relevant HTML that is part of your question so we can run your code.

Comment: If you could post the compiled CSS instead of the SCSS, and then also include the related HTML that will be a big help with anyone trying to answer your question.  Edit your question and press the button that looks like `[<>]` to make a runnable code snippet that will be in your question.

Comment: i've updated the codes, i dont really know if this work

Comment: I've done what @ChrisBarr mentioned and made a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552). See the linked article for how to make your own. I've also improved the English; one thing about English is that the "I" used to refer to oneself should always be capitalized. Also, your title appears to be missing a word; what is it that the banner should be doing smoothly that it isn't? See also [ask], which has some good tips for question writing.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm really new to this website so I don't really know how things work here.

Comment: you may use a library for this